# How to make `shared` Observable to allow firing a second observable once and not on each emission?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, multicast

I have a source observable, that I use for a WS Connection. That connection is opened `onMount`. On top of that, I fire another observable `onMount` to allow for a LoadingIndicator screen, until data arrive. I want that indicator to be present until data are emitted from the source observable, which I have done.

```js
  const mount$ = action$.pipe(Type.ON_MOUNT);

  const source$ = mount$.pipe(
    ... // Stuff happen here..
    share()
  );

  const setSuccess$ = source$.pipe(
    map(() => ({ type: Type.SET_LOADING, payload: false }))
  );

  const setLoading$ = mount$.pipe(map(() => ({ type: Type.SET_LOADING, payload: true })));

  return merge(source$, setLoading$, setSuccess$);
```

Then, I have the `setSucccess` observable, which is listening to the `source` observable emission, and sets `isLoading` to false. ***And here is the problem. That happens on every emission. I want that to happen only on the first one. How can I achieve that?***

I tried a few different things. I tried `shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })`, `take(1)` on the `setSuccess$` but nothing worked. ***How can I emit the second shared observable (setSuccess$) only once?***

Comment: `take(1)` should do what you want. What didn't work when you tried it?

Comment: That doesn’t work on slower connections. As the second subscriber is not emitted later as it should. While it does emit once I cannot really use it reliably..

Comment: use martins suggested `take(1)`, but try swapping your `merge()` with `concat()`, so that order is enforced and concurrency is not allowed.

Comment: I think I understand why `take(1)` doesn't work. When I do `source$.pipe(...)`, l  always have 1 subscriber thus the subscription won't work the second time. Any ideas on how to terminate my second subscription immediately.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to start `setLoading$` from  `mount$`. It is initially in loading state, so you can

```
return merge(source$, of({ type: Type.SET_LOADING, payload: true }), setSuccess$.pipe(take(1)));
```